# How to repack a customized firmware with Firmware Mod Kit?

Tags: filesystems, customization, extract, mount, firmware

I have been trying to mod a default firmware of a Digital Video Recorder just because of its splash screen logo, which is incredibly bright and almost blinds me everytime I turn it on at night.

I have tried to use the Firmware Mod Kit to extract the firmware from the binary file. Instead of coming across a squash or cram filesystem, I ended up with some zip compressed files. Here's some output:

```
Scan Time:     2015-08-17 23:28:44
Signatures:    193
Target File:   /home/king/fmk/myfirmware.bin
MD5 Checksum:  [omitted]

DECIMAL       HEX           DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0           Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compressed size: 2118527, uncompressed size: 2154560, name: "custom-x.cramfs.img"  
2118597       0x2053C5      Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compressed size: 2928495, uncompressed size: 2932800, name: "user-x.cramfs.img"  
5047160       0x4D0378      Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compressed size: 2424987, uncompressed size: 2445376, name: "romfs-x.cramfs.img"  
7472216       0x720458      Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compressed size: 18725, uncompressed size: 20544, name: "logo-x.cramfs.img"  
7491009       0x724DC1      Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compressed size: 141, uncompressed size: 354, name: "InstallDesc"  
7491611       0x72501B      End of Zip archive

Extracting 0 bytes of zip header image at offset 0
ERROR: No supported file system found! Aborting...
```

However, If I unzip the binary file, I can get FMK to extract the only file I'd really like to change: `logo-x.cramfs.img`:

```
king@castle:~/fmk$ ./extract-firmware.sh logo-x.cramfs.img:

Firmware Mod Kit (extract) 0.99, (c)2011-2013 Craig Heffner, Jeremy Collake

Preparing tools ...
Scanning firmware...

Scan Time:     2015-08-18 00:19:50
Signatures:    193
Target File:   /home/king/fmk/logo-x.cramfs.img
MD5 Checksum:  [omitted]

DECIMAL       HEX           DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0           uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x94AD77F7, created: Sun May 26 23:46:43 2013, image size: 20480 bytes, Data Address: 0x10770000, Entry Point: 0x10780000, data CRC: 0x8EDB113D, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: Standalone Program, compression type: gzip, image name: "linux"
64            0x40          CramFS filesystem, little endian size 20480 version #2 sorted_dirs CRC 0xbda508c, edition 0, 5 blocks, 2 files  

Extracting 64 bytes of uimage header image at offset 0
Extracting cramfs file system at offset 64
Extracting CramFS file system...
```

Now I'm not sure how to proceed. build-firmware script won't mount it back to an `.img` file, and even if it does, I can't repack the initial binary as well because I had to manually extract it instead of doing via extract-firmware script.

Thoughts? I don't really want to brick my dvr, almost giving this up. Any helpful comments are largely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In fmk it's not possible.
It's more complicated process since you need to generate headers ... all steps here:
http://sysmagazine.com/posts/213411/

Comment: Do you have source of original article? The aboved link is obsolete.